# Centos8 - mysql cpp connector issues

Tags: c++, centos, mysql-connector

I've facing problem in establishing MySQL C++ Connector in Centos 8. Ive installed the following :

```
rpm -ivh https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm
dnf repolist all | grep mysql | grep enabled 
dnf install -y --disablerepo=appstream mysql-community-server
systemctl status mysqld
systemctl start mysqld
```

```
$ rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
mysql-community-common-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
mysql80-community-release-el8-3.noarch
mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
mysql-connector-c++-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
```

I'm getting `fatal error: mysql_connection.h: No such file or directory`

#include "mysql_connection.h". If

what am I missing folks?

Comment: First find where is this header file located after installation. Run `updatedb; locate mysql_connection.h`. It may list some paths where this file is present. Check if those paths are in system PATH variable. If yes, then try changing to `#include <mysql_connection.h>` (not sure, maybe it detects it with this, if it doesn't work edit the post and add what new information you found and what you tried).

Comment: @kiner_shah
Thanks man. It worked, but I got further errors as follows: /tmp/ccujsuFy.o: In function `check_lib()':
1.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

/tmp/ccujsuFy.o: In function `get_driver_instance_by_name':
1.cpp:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `_get_driver_instance_by_name'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Also, I'm compiling the code with : g++ 1.cpp -lmysqlcppconn8

Comment: Linking libraries involves linking the libraries present in some library path and including the headers for that library in some include path. Try compiling using something like `g++ -L /path/to/library -lmysqlcppconn8 -I /path/to/include 1.cpp`.

Comment: @kiner_shah  For, g++ 1.cpp -lmysqlcppconn8  -L/usr/lib64 -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/jdbc

Still I'm getting the error : 
undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

undefined reference to `_get_driver_instance_by_name'

Comment: Where is this `check` function defined?